# Is there a GWT theme similar to Github?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm looking for a theme for GWT that has a similar look-and-feel to Github.  Can anyone provide any pointers to good GWT themes that are under a GPL-compatible license?

Comment: GWT CSS is a day of work max. I made my own in about that time, I believe.

Comment: road to yamburg, any interesting in contributing to a really worthwhile open source project? ;-)  https://github.com/sanity/tahrir/wiki

Answer (score 1):

I would use [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) in the following way: get the page you like, retrieve its source code, either html and css (firebug is useful to this purpouse, for example) and then make your own UiBinder template.